# Is there somewhere I can download just Visual Studio Command prompt for VS 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

I need it for a Sharepoint project I'm working on.

Comment: You can just use the regular command prompt. The VS Command Prompt isn't really anything special. Run the "vcvarsall.bat" file to register the environment variables as required to access the SDK tools.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that... I have VS 2010 tools intalled.  I copied that file over from the 10.0 folder and ran it but it errored out.  Is there something specific I should change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step-by-step guide straight from Redmond:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859.aspx

> The required environment variable
>   values are provided by the sdkvars.bat
>   batch file located in the SDK\v2.0\bin
>   folder. The SDK Command Prompt calls
>   this batch file, but the variables
>   expire when you close the command
>   prompt.
>
> To make the settings permanent, you
>   can add the variable values to your
>   system variables by using the
>   **Environment Variables** dialog box,
>   which you can access from the **Advanced**
>   tab of **System Properties**.

Comment: whoa... newish user here-- other people can edit my answers? TIL.

Comment: Took me to 4.0 instructions but found what I needed easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the command line version of the Visual Studio 2008 C/C++ compiler
with the Windows SDK (starting with the SDK update for Vista, I believe)

[Windows SDK web](http://microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=3138)

[Windows SDK ISO](http://microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=18950)

The "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4" includes the VS
2010 C/C++ compiler instead of the VS2008 version
(which may or may not work for you).

You can also still get the VS 2008 compiler by downloading the VC++ 2008
Express

[Visual Studio ISO](http://microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=13276)

Even though it installs the Express IDE, you can still use the command line
compiler just fine.